# keep old status with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqxhr

I have downloaded 1 upload progress bar from here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress3.html

It's perfect; anyway, just when the file is uploaded it gives a status about file, like:

> file uploaded in http://mysite.com/1.jpg

However, when a new file is uploaded, the status disappears and details about the new file that has just been uploaded come up.

I want to just have the old status and when a new file is uploaded, the new status just comes up under the old status.  How could I do this?

Here's the code:

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');
$('form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
    //console.log(percentVal, position, total);
},
complete: function(xhr) {
    status.html(xhr.responseText);
}
}); 

})();       
</script>
```

If you see the [demo](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/progress3.html) in the link and understand it well, the status appears inside the HTML that looks like:

```
 <div id="status"></div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `complete` callback is resetting `status.html()`, AND your `beforeSend` is emptying `status` with `status.empty();`. Remove that line!

Then try [prepending](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) the newest message wrapped in some markup, rather than overwriting the entire contents of `status`:

```
complete: function(xhr) {
    var message = '<div class="new">' + xhr.responseText + '</div>';
    status.prepend(message);
}
```

Comment: sry but i know noting about jquery im php programmer can u give me example?

Comment: `status.html(status.html() + xhr.responseText);` (But this will depend on your html structure)

Comment: not work
  status.html(status.html() + xhr.responseText);
    }

Comment: status.prepend(xhr.responseText.wrap('<div class="new" />')); not even work for first file now

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the functionality of jQuery's `wrap` method. I updated my answer with a way to prepend a manually constructed string of html containing the `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: Also, I didn't notice at first that you wanted the new status to come up _under_ the old one. If that's still the case, just change `prepend(message)` to `append(message)`

Comment: your edited answer is clean div status too after upload new file :(

Comment: I just noticed that you're also emptying `status` in your `beforeSend` function. Re-read my updated answer.

Comment: http://royta.org/file/pic/photo/2013/01/0c4e8fc0c80c0b96bf36e3bf3c6d7ef8_1024.jpg? the demo of my upload center